# How to connect to a wireless network in Lubuntu

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I just don't know how to turn on my Wi-Fi or choose a Wi-Fi connection.
I'm now using the cable, but I really need to use the Wi-Fi on school. How to do that?

Comment: Add your wireless adapter model

Comment: Which release of Lubuntu you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your applications, bottom left of screen, if I remember correctly.

Find System Settings.  Click on Network.

Click on Wireless, then turn on wireless.

It should scan available networks and allow you to connect if you have network password.

NEW INFO

Try re-setting your network services first.

```
sudo service networking restart
```

or this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Then go back to see your Network Settings to see if wifi is working.

Comment: ok, there must be something wong with my computer then... it happens i have done that bebore, and what i get by that is the option to create a wifi connection, and i'm really like, a foot away from my wireless router...

Comment: And, you see no available networks?

Comment: Open terminal and run ifconfig, look for wlan0 and check the status.

Comment: i only see the "ethernet cable conection"

Comment: wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:23:4d:42:75:55  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Comment: I edited the answer with NEW INFO.  Try that.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>